# Options site set empty fields after submitting

Tags: wp-admin, options

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fhwtest_plugin_menu' );

function fhwtest_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Reservierungs-Einstellungen', 'Reservierung', 'administrator', 'fhwtest_reservoptions', 'fhwtest_plugin_options_seite' );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'fhwtest_plugin_options' );
}

function fhwtest_plugin_options() {
    register_setting( 'fhwtest_settings_group1', 'fhwtest_bahnzahl' );
    register_setting( 'fhwtest_settings_group1', 'fhwtest_email' );
    register_setting( 'fhwtest_settings_group1', 'fhwtest_datenbankname' );
}

function fhwtest_plugin_options_seite() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_die( __( 'Keine Berechtigung' ) );
    }
?>
    <style>
        fieldset { 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            padding: 15px; 
        }
        legend { font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Reservierungs-Einstellungen</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'fhwtest_settings_group1' ); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections( 'fhwtest_settings_group1' ); ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Bahnen</legend>
                <label>Anzahl Bahnen: 
                    <input type="number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'fhwtest_bahnzahl' ) ); ?>" name="bahnzahl" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Benachrichtigung</legend>
                <label>E-Mail an 
                    <input name="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'fhwtest_email' ) ); ?>" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Datenbank</legend>
                <label>Datenbankname
                    <input name="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'fhwtest_datenbankname' ) ); ?>" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>       
    </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

The site is correct, but if I type in values and save it, all the fields are empty again. Why aren't they saved?

Comment: Without looking your code:  check the database for your meta data. Was it saved? Or you just can't get it?
HTML is a cutie pie but brings nothing to solve a problem.

Comment: @MaxYudin Its not saved in the database, the "fhwtest_bahnzahl", "fhwtest_email", "fhwtest_datenbankname" are existing, but there's no option_value. Is the option_id relevant? Should it be ascending? There are some counting fails.

Comment: You have to find a way to save it to the database. There are hundreds of tutorials around. This site is not a tutorial.

Comment: @MaxYudin I know. As said in the question before you edited it, it was working. I was using this https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages. I used google since one hour and can't find the problem while comparing my code with the one in the tutorials.

Comment: It was working, now it's not. Figure out the change you've made before things happened.

  P.S. I did not edit the post, I just removed incomprehensible and useless information which does not help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note in your code:

1. Two inputs share the same name of "email", so when those values get sent in the form submission, the second one will overwrite the first.
2. The input `name` attribute value should match the name of the option being saved. Instead of "email", use "fhwtest_email". Without that, the values won't be saved to the correct options.
3. `get_option()` will return `false` if there's not a value set for the requested option name; if you pass `false` to `esc_attr()` it'll return an empty string, so the next save will set the value to an empty string.

While there are certainly lots of ways to approach the creation of settings, I suggest taking a look at the [Plugin Developer's Handbook section on Settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/) for sample code and details into the Settings and Options APIs.